# Notifications across all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, browser, notifications, web-notifications

Are there any sort of notification system that works with all major browsers? I know chrome has their Notification API, Safari has push notifications and IE has pinned sites but is there some more general way to show notifications? I did find https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications which uses a combination of different notifications (though I still can't seem to get the demo working in IE).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are there any sort of notification system that works with all major browsers?

The mechanism https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/ defines is the only standard notification system for web apps that’s intended to work the same across all browsers. It’s supported in all current major browsers: Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and all other Chrome-based browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API

Comment: This project can't has onclick event. If it is upgraded for this feature that all of major browsers supports, it will be perfect for everyone.

Comment: Wow, IE + Edge holding up everything. Deja vu much?

Comment: What kind of code has to be written on Server side for pushing notifications to browser?

Comment: Actually Edge is supported as you can see from the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#Browser_compatibility) table. The only unsupported browser among the major ones is Internet Explorer, although there are some minor restrictions in Safari and Firefox too.